# Android custom player and third party player taking 20 to 30 sec to play video

Tags: android, performance, video

I am working on Android App regarding video playing. I am facing 20 to 30 seconds delay in video playing. I have tried many players but issue was always same. should i use Android custom or third party player for video playing. or anyone can suggest me alternative approach. videos size is 5mb and in mp4 format. how can i minimize this time to 1 to 2 sec.

Comment: Have you tried ExoPlayer ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it also. It was taking 12 to 20 sec to play video.

Comment: Is the video streamed from the internet or stored locally on the Android device?

Comment: @Mick it is stored on Amazon Aws S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of your issue it may simply be that the metadata is at the end of the container for the video, which is typical with mp4 videos.

For video you want to stream it is recommended to move this to the front of the video.

You can see some more info and examples here:

- https://superuser.com/a/438471
- https://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/